Do i need to replace the iPhone at the store for iPhone upgrade program?
I am doing in-store pickup but I want to take it back home with me to do the transfer and make sure all my 2FA (two-factor authentication) apps are properly transferred over, etc before I return the old (current) phone back in-store to complete the iPhone upgrade.
When we do the mail-in kit, it says we have 14 days, so there is a period where we would have both phones are home, but just wondering if this is possible with in-store pickup also.
Do I need to replace the iPhone at the store at pickup to walk away with the new one for the iPhone upgrade program?

The iPhone Upgrade Program page (https://www.apple.com/shop/iphone/iphone-upgrade-program/upgrade) reads "You’ll also have the option to pick up your new iPhone in a store. When you come to the store, remember to bring your current iPhone with you to trade in. Be sure you back up your data on your current iPhone to your computer or iCloud before trading it in." so it seems you can't take the old iPhone back home with you. If you upgrade online or with the Apple Store app, though, you have a grace period and you can transfer your data, as you mention, so that could be a better option for you.

Yes. Plan for leaving the old phone at the store.

I would call the store if you need to be sure, but in the past they are staffed and schedule setup reservations to ensure your transfer is good and you don’t walk out with both phones.
